# Changing OS file icons using AIR app

Tags: air, filesystems, icons, overlay

I am building an AIR app which will be kind of like Dropbox. It will allow users to sync their files between various OSs. What I would like to know is that how can i change the default file system's file icons (add an overlay for eg) for states like - Synced and Syncing, the way Dropbox does it ??
On Windows i found out that Dropbox edits the registry files to insert the overlay icons..not yet sure how they do it in MAC OS X though. 
I saw some threads here asking similar questions about AIR, but none referencing how to change file's icons. Hoping to get a solution for this from the various experts .. Please suggest any ideas if you know how it can be accomplished. Much thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A simple yet effective solution would be to use icons that are only *internal* to your application : just embed in your application files some transparent pictures representing the various states of your files (with only the small part telling in which state it is, with the rest totally transparent), that you will add at runtime above the displayed icons.

Since you can get the actual icon of your files, just draw them into a BitmapData (if needed) & add an overlay with theses custom images, using the one related to your file's state in your application.

And one step further could be to store in your AIR application folder any resulting icons for future use (check what types of files you already have, and if your new file type isn't in thoses, export the various icons with your custom overlays to PNG files directly on the user device, for re-loading them the next time the application is opened).

Comment: Thanks Bertrand for your idea. Quick question - how do i "add the icon at runtime above the displayed icons ?" (As that is the main issue I am not able to figure out.) How do through AIR app i add the overlays on top of file system icons ??

Comment: I might not have made me clear enough :-) With AIR you can have access to a file type icon via the File class .icon property (returning a BitmapData). You can then just draw on it another MovieClip (your overlay) to have your final icon. After that, you can either save that file to the user hard drive (and load it next time the app is launched) or just keep it in memory until you app is closed (and rebuild it everytime the app is launched). Sorry if I cannot explain clearly enough that concept, I'll try to post a picture to explain my thoughts.

Comment: Oh, i see what you mean..but the file's 'icon' property is read-only..I do not think that it could be modified. Is there something i might be missing ?

Comment: Just use the clone() function of the icon's BitmapData, you'll get a new BitmapData containing the icon of the file, which you'll be able to modify to add your overlay.

Comment: Yes, all that i understand, but it is not possible to alter the icon that is being shown for the files in the OS. I need a way to update the files icon as well. Sorry if i was not clear. What do you think about this Bertrand ??

Comment: I think you've misunderstood me : I know altering the OS icons is not possible, I was just proposing you a way to "visually" alter them **only inside** your application. Its a kind of _temporary_ solution that will only show the modified icons inside your AIR application while its running and will not change the actual icon files used by the OS. But I'd say its the only solution for having custom made file icons. If you're looking for some way of changing the OS files, I'm sorry I don't have any solution for you, and I'm afraid no solution exists at all.

Comment: Thanks Bertrand. Yes I do have to modify the icons in the file system. They do it in Dropbox..so was wondering if anyone would have ideas about it. Thanks for your help. :)